# How to know if the managed package is comply with Privacy shield framework?

Tags: data, framework, data-protection-and-privacy

Is there any possibility/link to understand if the managed packages that we installed/built are complying with privacy shield framework?

I didn't see any links or documents which shows the details on this request. I am able to get this [link](https://www.privacyshield.gov/participant_search#) but wasn't sure if that's the correct place to check it?

Any thoughts would be helpful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you are considering applying encryption against standard or custom fields (the latter from *other* packages):

1. If you have already enabled encryption on a (standard or custom) field that the package to be installed uses in an incompatible manner (e.g. in static SOQL/SOSL WHERE clause using LIKE, ORDER BY etc.) then the installation of that package will fail with an error. However, if this inappropriate usage is in dynamic SOQL/SOSL then the package will install but will suffer from runtime exceptions when the dynamic querying is performed.
2. If the package is already installed then you may get an error when trying to enable encryption on a field (or suffer from runtime exceptions) again depending on whether Salesforce is able to statically analyse the package code and detect incompatibilities.

According to the [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.securityImplGuide.meta/securityImplGuide/security_pe_managed_packages.htm), ISVs can explicitly permit shield against custom fields in their package and you'll see indication on the App Exchange listing.